# Loop to validate user input

Tags: java, loops

I am fairly new to Java and I am trying to write a small program that asks a user to enter 3 integers between 1-10, stores them in an array and then adds up the integers and tells the user the answer. I have written this so far and it works:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Feb11a {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] numArr = new int[3];
        int sum = 0;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 3 numbers in the range 1 to 10: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < numArr.length; i++) {
            numArr[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
        }

        for (int counter = 0; counter < numArr.length; counter++) {
            sum += numArr[counter];
        }

        System.out.println("The sum of these numbers is " + sum);
    }
}
```

My problem is I am also meant to validate the input as in if they enter a double, a string or a number outside the 1-10 range. I have tried a while loop but I just cannot get the program to work, below is what I have so far. If I take out the first while loop the second one works i.e. it checks if it is an integer:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Feb11a {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] numArr = new int[3];
        int sum = 0;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i < numArr.length; i++) {
            //check if between 1 and 10
            while (i > 10 || i < 1) {
                System.out.println("Enter a number in the range 1 to 10: ");

                //check if integer      
                while (!keyboard.hasNextInt()) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid entry, please try again ");
                    keyboard.next();
                }
                numArr[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
            }
        }

        for (int counter = 0; counter < numArr.length; counter++) {
            sum += numArr[counter];
        }

        System.out.println("The sum of these numbers is " + sum);
    }
}
```

My question is how do I get it to check if it is an integer and if it is the range 1-10?

Comment: Your for-loop loops as many times as there are items in your array. However, you don't check the value of the array. You check the iteration i (while (i>10 || i<1). You need to iterate through the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewClass {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

int[] numArr = new int[3];
int sum=0,x;
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);



  for(int i=0; i<numArr.length; i++)
 {
        //check if between 1 and 10
     System.out.println("Enter a number in the range 1 to 10: ");

                //check if integer      
    while (!keyboard.hasNextInt())
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid entry, please try again ");
        keyboard.next();
    }
            x = keyboard.nextInt();
           if(x>0 && x<=10)
             numArr[i]=x;
           else{
               System.out.println("Retry Enter a number in the range 1 to 10:");
               i--;
           }

}


     for (int counter=0; counter<numArr.length; counter++)
    {
        sum+=numArr[counter];
    }
    System.out.println("The sum of these numbers is "+sum);
 }

}
```

Comment: @user127378 Please consider to mark as answer in addition if you find a good answer you have to upvote by the time you can do so

Comment: ok, how do I mark as answer. I just edited my name by the way....just figured it out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To check simple use [Integer.parseInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) and catch the NumberFormatException (together with Scanner.next()).

Once format is correct you can do an int comparison `(i>0 && i<11)`.

Comment: And what if they enter 11?

Comment: I'm still very new to java and I haven't come across the Integer.parseInt() yet. What is it used for?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `NumberUtils` under `org.apache.commons.lang.math`

It has `isDigits` method to check whether given string contains only digits or not:

```
if (NumberUtils.isDigits(str) && NumberUtils.toInt(str) < 10) {
    // your requirement
}
```

Note that `toInt` returns zero for big numbers!

Maybe for just this reason adding a whole library seems unnecessary but for bigger projects you will need such libraries like [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) and [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the System in into a BufferedReader to read whatever the user has to input, then check if its an 'int' and repeat input from user.

I have modified your code a little bit to make it work.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Feb11a {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException
    // You may want to handle the Exceptions when calling the getInt function
    {
        Feb11a tester = new Feb11a();
        tester.perform();
    }

    public void perform() throws NumberFormatException, IOException
    {
        int[] numArr = new int[3];
        int sum = 0;
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        for (int i = 0; i < numArr.length; i++) 
        {
            int anInteger = -1;
            do
            {
                // First get input from user.
                System.out.println("Enter a number in the range 1 to 10: ");
                anInteger = getInt(in);
            } while (anInteger > 10 || anInteger < 1);  // then check for repeat condition. Not between 1 and 10.

            numArr[i] = anInteger;  // set the number into the array.
        }


        for (int counter = 0; counter < numArr.length; counter++) 
        {
            sum += numArr[counter];
        }
        System.out.println("The sum of these numbers is " + sum);
    }

    public int getInt(BufferedReader br) throws NumberFormatException, IOException
    {
        String str = br.readLine();
        int toReturn = Integer.parseInt(str);
        return toReturn;
    }
}
```